# How to prove a function is in $L_2(G)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

For $G$ is open bounded set in $\mathbf{R}^n$,
$L_2(G)$ is defined as 
$$L_2(G) = \{f:G\rightarrow \mathbf{R} \text{  measurable}: \int |f|^2<\infty\}$$

Now, I want to prove that $f:\mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }x\in \mathbf{Q} \\
0, & \text{if }x\notin \mathbf{Q}
\end{cases}
$$
is in $L_2(\mathbf{R})$

I can prove that $f$ is measurable via Borel Algebra or $\mathbf{X}=\big\{\emptyset,\mathbf{R},\mathbf{Q},\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{Q}\big\}$

But, how can we prove that the integral of $f$ is finite?

Comment: Use the definition of the integral, together with the fact that $|\mathbb{Q}| = 0$.

Comment: @t-bongers: Dear T, what is $|.|$?

Comment: @barrymikhael: That's the Lebesque measure of the set $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @barrymikhael It's one of the notations for Lebesgue measure; it's equivalent to $m(\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: @t-bongers: I have no idea what kind of simple function I should use

Comment: Try $0 \cdot \Xi_{G-Q} + 1 \cdot \Xi_{Q}$

Comment: @rrl: the integral is defined as supremum of integral of simple functions, is it OK if we are just taking one simple function?

Comment: Isn't that simple function the same as f?

Comment: Oh ya, I get it, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $f^2 = f$ and $f$ is a simple function (namely, $f = 1 \chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$), we have that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^2 dm = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f dm = 1 \cdot m(\mathbb{Q}) = 0$$

since $m(\mathbb{Q}) = 0$.